# React Navbar fix on scroll 300

Tags: reactjs, navbar

I'm working on a react app. Initially my header is set on top and I want header to get appear when a page scroll down to 300 and vice-versa. I do have also 'GoToTop' button on my page. I want to set both header and button to appear onto page when a page scroll down to 300.

I tried to get my desired result for button first and luckily I succeed. Now I want to do this for my header too. I'm not getting what should I do to set header visible and/or hidden. I need help.

my code for GoToTop button is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './style.scss';

class ScrollToTop extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            is_visible: false
           
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        var scrollComponent = this;
        document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
            scrollComponent.toggleVisibility();
        });
    }
    toggleVisibility() {
        if (window.pageYOffset > 300) {
            this.setState({
                is_visible: true
                
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                is_visible: false
                
            });
        }
    }
    scrollToTop() {
        window.scrollTo({
            top: 0,
            behavior: "smooth"
        });
    }
    
    render() {
        const { is_visible } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                {is_visible && (
                    <div onClick={() => this.scrollToTop()}>
                        <div className='BackToTop'>
                            <a className='WrapContainer'>
                                <div className='ArrowContainer'>
                                    <div className='Arrow'></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default ScrollToTop;
```

My header(navbar) is already there in my app. My thought is to import Header in this button.js file and use. If my approach is possible then how can I do this?

This is the [link](https://preview.colorlib.com/theme/jackco/) for your reference to know what I'm trying to get

and here's [CodeSandbox](https://b9i0f.csb.app/) of my work.

Answer (score 0):

it's `window.scrollY` to catch the value of the scroll.

See the code bellow, it should work

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './style.scss';

class ScrollToTop extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            is_visible: false
           
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        var scrollComponent = this;
        document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
            scrollComponent.toggleVisibility();
        });
    }
    toggleVisibility() {
        if (window.scrollY > 300) {
            this.setState({
                is_visible: true
                
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                is_visible: false
                
            });
        }
    }
    scrollToTop() {
        window.scrollTo({
            top: 0,
            behavior: "smooth"
        });
    }
    
    render() {
        const { is_visible } = this.state;
        return (
            <div style={is_visible ? {} : {display: 'none'}}>
                    <div onClick={() => this.scrollToTop()}>
                        <div className='BackToTop'>
                            <a className='WrapContainer'>
                                <div className='ArrowContainer'>
                                    <div className='Arrow'></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default ScrollToTop;
```

Comment: GregMit, my code in the question is working fine for button because its only for button obviously. Here I'm not pointing you out but your solution seems only for button too. Where I want to set navbar to appear and hide when page scroll down. I want to know is there any way settle down navbar in same code?

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't get your question right. Yes you can apply the exact same logic to a navbar @xKodian

Comment: GregMit, do i need to write this two times i mean one is for button and second is for navbar? But doing this doesn't seem optimization of code and standard of coding. am i right?

Comment: You can for example use a Context or use the same logic in the parent component, by this I mean watching the state of the parent component to render the button and the navbar as you want @xKodian

Comment: GregMit, i tried to do the same as you suggested before putting my question here and it was throwing error. Do you have code sample or any reference for the same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, can you create a code sandbox with your code so I can show you an example in your context ?

Comment: GregMit, i hope you will be going good. Here's the code sandbox's link: https://b9i0f.csb.app/ For some XYZ reason(s) images are not getting load in app. I'm checking them out. So for now please don't consider images.